# A request to allow links to be opened in a new tab

Tags: feature-request, design

Often when working my way through a question or answer there are several links in the middle of the text for references.  It would be nice if I could click on that and not lose my place on the page I was reading but rather have the link open up in a new window.  Is this something that can be easily configured on SE?

Edit:  For people with poor internet connections this is a nice feature because I often have to abandon a page because it takes too long to load and if I accidentally just close it I have to start all over again.  I had no idea it was unpopular because it is a common feature on almost every forum or other site I use.

Comment: It's rather annoying to have open in new tab as the default behavior for links. 

I personally use middle-click (click the scroll wheel) or Ctrl-click for this and it's pretty convenient.

Comment: This has, thankfully, been turned down every time it has been brought up on the mother meta. (Actually the first time was during the UserVoice era *before* meta.) I should ***never*** have to look at the destination of a link to see how it will behave.

Comment: Links related to my claim above: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/make-links-posted-by-users-open-in-a-new-window (first case on meta) and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168063/allow-per-user-settings-to-open-external-links-in-the-same-or-a-new-tab (asking for it to be user configurable).

Comment: Ah, yes. There is (or at least was) [a userscript which implements this misfeature](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/59563) for anyone who really wants it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, you have the choice of opening in the current tab or a new one (e.g. middle click, ctrl click). Your idea would only permit the latter.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean, but then again I don't have a middle button either.  Ctrl+leftclick works great for me though, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

No, SE doesn't have a setting to allow this. I recommend holding down Ctrl (on a non-Mac) or Command (on a Mac) while clicking a link to get it to open in a new tab. Alternatively, you could check and see if your browser has a setting to do this by default, or if there is an extension/addon that will let you configure it.